# How to avoid language cache with NgJhipsterModule

Tags: jhipster

I have an angular 4 application generated by **Jhipster** and I'm using **NgJhipsterModule** to load the ***.json** language files as follow:

```
NgJhipsterModule.forRoot({
     alertAsToast: false,
     i18nEnabled: true,
     defaultI18nLang: 'en'
});
```

The issue is NgJhipsterModule is making an AJAX request to **/i18n/en.json** and browser is loading from its cache.

I want to be able to add like a hash build number to the ***.json** files e.g. **/i18n/en.c48ee647e250b0df5984.json** to avoid the browser cache, similar to hash build number used in Webpack.

Is there a way to achieve this with **Jhipster**?

Comment: So you found a bug, please report it on github. The issue is that webpack hashing requires to modify source code like HTML templates for images and here the code is ng-jhipster library not in generated code.

Comment: As a workaround you could append a random value (or timestamp) in a query string parameter to these requests using an http interceptor somehting like /i18n/en.jso?cache-buster=201709301245

Comment: @GaëlMarziou using http interceptor with random value is not a bad workaround but also doesn't solve the issue where I don't want on every user F5 to reload a new **en.json?cache-buster=**, Basically, I still want the browser to be able to cache the file. In other words, I want somehow to invalidate the browser cache when I deploy a new version of the app.

Comment: Yes this is why I called it a workaround not a solution. But you can adapt the interceptor to use something like app version (there's a constant for it).